# Oracle 10g SQL transpose rows to columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an EMPLOYEE Table in Oracle 10g with say the following fields and data, wherein EMPID is unique, grade is the current level of the employee in the organization, and DOJ is the date of joining the organization.

```
EMPID |NAME|GRADE|DOJ
---------------------------------
111111|AAA |A1   |01-01-2010
---------------------------------
222222|BBB |A3   |01-04-2010
---------------------------------
333333|CCC |A4   |01-03-2010
---------------------------------
```

And a EMPLOYEE_GROWTH Table which shows the date of entry in each successive grades till date for each employee as shown below

```
EMPID |GRADE|ENTRY_DT
--------------------------
111111|A1   |01-01-2010
--------------------------
222222|A1   |01-04-2010
--------------------------
222222|A2   |01-07-2012
--------------------------
222222|A3   |01-07-2016
--------------------------
333333|A1   |01-03-2010
--------------------------
333333|A2   |01-07-2012
--------------------------
333333|A3   |01-07-2014
--------------------------
333333|A4   |01-07-2017
--------------------------
```

Now I want to write a SQL query in Oracle to get the following report as output

```
EMPID |GD1|ENTRY_DT1 |GD2|ENTRY_DT2 |GD3|ENTRY_DT3 |GD4|ENTRY_DT4
------------------------------------------------------------------
111111|A1 |01-01-2010|   |          |   |          |   |          
------------------------------------------------------------------
222222|A1 |01-04-2010|A2 |01-07-2012|A3 |01-07-2016|   |          
------------------------------------------------------------------
333333|A1 |01-03-2010|A2 |01-07-2012|A3 |01-07-2014|A4 |01-07-2017
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SQL is not made for that. you can do it but i advice you to do that after in your viz tool after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First transform rows to columns using `CASE`. Then pick the valid value and group it based on PK.

```
SELECT 
EMP_ID,
MAX(GD1) AS GD1,
MAX(ENTRY_DT1) AS ENTRY_DT1,
MAX(GD2) AS GD2,
MAX(ENTRY_DT2) AS ENTRY_DT2,
MAX(GD3) AS GD3,
MAX(ENTRY_DT3) AS ENTRY_DT3
FROM
(SELECT EMPID,
CASE WHEN GRADE='A1' THEN GRADE END AS GD1,
CASE WHEN GRADE='A1' THEN ENTRY_DT END AS ENTRY_DT1,
CASE WHEN GRADE='A2' THEN GRADE END AS GD2,
CASE WHEN GRADE='A2' THEN ENTRY_DT END AS ENTRY_DT2,
CASE WHEN GRADE='A3' THEN GRADE END AS GD3,
CASE WHEN GRADE='A3' THEN ENTRY_DT END AS ENTRY_DT3
FROM EMPLOYEE_GROWTH )TR 
GROUP BY EMP_ID
```

Comment: I do not think it is working ... the SQL limit the number of grade to 3 .... example show 4 grades. Need something more scalable

Comment: User did not mention the number of grades that may occur in the data set. The report shows till GD4.

Comment: there can be upto 20 grades

Comment: @rahul In that case, you may need to go with that many case statements.

Comment: @voidpro i tried ur query, but it is always giving a missing keyword error 00905 at the first case statement near AS

Comment: @voidpro ya i made as many case statements as required but there seems to be something wrong as it's giving missing keyword error

Comment: just missing `end` before `as`. But as I said before, this is not the right way to do it. Do that in the app receiving the data.

Comment: @StevenBENET updated the code. This might not be the best fit. The performance depends on the size of data set though.

Comment: @StevenBENET thanks for your suggestion and reply, it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try the techniques mentioned in below website to convert rows into columns:

http://www.expert-oracle.com/how-to-convert-rows-into-columns-using-sql-in-oracle/